# sum all occurrences of range values in other range

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

There are two sheets.

Sheet1:

| Surname | Frst | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bernard | Shaw | SectionA | SectionB | SectionD | SectionF |
| Lincoln | Abel | SectionB | SectionE |  |  |
| Shakesp | Earl | SectionA | SectionE | SectionH |  |

Sheet2:

| Group1 | Group2 | Group3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SectionA | SectionD | SectionG |
| SectionB | SectionE | SectionH |
| SectionC | SectionF | SectionI |

I want to count all occurrences of Sheet 2 column 1, all occurrences of Sheet 2 column 2 (etc) in each row of Sheet 1.  For example:

| Surname | Frst | Grp1 | Grp2 | Grp3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bernard | Shaw | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| Lincoln | Abel | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Shakesp | Earl | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I have tried countifs and count and vlookups with limited success. Example:

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!C1:Y1,@'Sheet2'!A:A)`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Google Sheets is not Excel. Please ensure your tags are appropriate to your situation.

Comment: That does not look like a valid implementation of `COUNTIFS`. It seems to be missing the criteria for the two provided ranges. [This may be of use](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

Comment: Yes, I appreciate your thoughts.  I replied to the suggestion below which is not exactly what I was hoping for...  In the title of my post I reference 2 ranges...  I'm really looking for something more like this as per my example above (note the 2nd range):  =COUNTIF($C3:$F3,"Sheet2!A$10:A")

Answer (score 2):

I not sure using `@` will be working or not, as I am getting `error` by testing your formula, however there is a simple method to solve your problem by using `countif` also, the only difference is that I will count on criteria on each `row` and add up all, here is the formula:

```
=COUNTIF($C3:$F3,A$10)+COUNTIF($C3:$F3,A$11)+COUNTIF($C3:$F3,A$12)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thought, and I had looked at this, but I was hoping to select a range for the group count as opposed to individually counting each row per group...  Something like:  =COUNTIF($C3:$F3,"Sheet2!A$10:A") but this does not work.

Comment: I think `countif` is expect a single condition, when you using a range as criteria, then you are trying to input `multiple criteria` at the same time. Formula always has its own limitation.

Comment: Yes, I know the limitations of countif...  I'm simply trying to explain the sort of functionality I'm looking for...  Pretty sure I've found it though: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Sheet1!C2:F2,Sheet2!A:A))

Comment: Great you found it!